# Including C++ headers in user mode programs built with NT DDK

Tags: c++, c, windows, kernel, wdk

So...I have a kernel mode component and a user mode component I'm putting together using the turnkey build environment of the [NT DDK 7.1.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/gg487458).  The kernel component is all .c/.h/.rc files.  The user mode component is .cpp/.c/.h/.rc files.

At first it seemed simplest to use **build** for both, as I saw you could modify the `./sources` file of the user mode component to say something like:

```
TARGETNAME = MyUserModeComponent
TARGETTYPE = PROGRAM
UMTYPE = windows
UMENTRY = winmain
USE_MSVCRT = 1
```

That didn't seem to cause a problem and so I was pleased, until I tried to `#include <string>` (or `<memory>`, or whatever)  Doesn't find that stuff:

> error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'string': No such file or directory

Still, it's compiling the user mode piece with C++ language semantics.  But how do I get the standard includes to work?

I don't technically need to use the DDK **build** tool for the user mode piece.  I could make a visual studio solution.  I'm a bit wary as I have bumped into other annoyances, like the fact that the DDK uses `__stdcall` instead of `__cdecl` by default... and there isn't any pragma or compiler switch to override this.  You literally have to go into each declaration you care about and change it, assuming you have source to do so.  :-/

I'm starting to wonder if this is just a fractal descent into *"just because you CAN doesn't mean you SHOULD build user mode apps with the DDK.  Here be dragons."*  So my question isn't just about this particular technical hurdle, but rather if I should abandon the idea of building a C++ user mode component with the DDK tools...just because the kernel component is pure C.

Comment: VC++ has a command line switch to set the default calling convention.

Comment: @CaptainOblivious Yes, but how can that be used with the NT DDK `sources` file... ?  :-)  It doesn't use the VC++ compiler AFAIK.  This stuff seems a world unto its own, with lots of "do not edit this file" and I would say the *here be dragons* is a good refrain for working with this build environment.  The include directories allow `../foo/bar` but the source directories don't do paths like that.  I'm bewildered about what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build a user mode program with WINDDK you need to add some variables to your SOURCES file:

- `386_STDCALL=0` to use `cdecl` calling convention by default
- `USE_STL=1` to use STL
- `USE_NATIVE_EH=1` to add a support for exception handling

Everything else you already have.

I'll put my full SOURCES file for reference:

```
TARGETNAME = MyUserModeComponent
TARGETTYPE = PROGRAM
TARGETPATH = obj
UMTYPE = console
UMENTRY = main

USE_MSVCRT = 1
USE_NATIVE_EH=1
USE_STL=1
386_STDCALL=0

SOURCES= main.cpp
```

And main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "bla bla bla!";
    cout << s;

    return 0;
}
```

Have fun!

Comment: This is nice +1 for showing the details of SOURCES; however the problem is that he's wants to build a full blown windows program and not a console application, which is why the issue with calling conventions

Comment: @AhmedMasud This does seem to work for a full blown win app, but it does require the changes I listed to UMTYPE and UMENTRY.  Well, the collective knowledge of the Internet grows every day here.  :-)  Thanks Sergius!

Answer (score 2):

## Quick Answer

Abandon the idea of building user-mode components with DDK tools *(although I find the concept fascinating :-P)*

Your kernel mode component should be built separately from the user mode components as a matter of good practice.

## Vague thoughts

Off the top of my head, and this really speaking from limited experience...there are a lot of subtle differences that can creep up if you try to mix the two together.

Using your own example of __cdecl vs __stdcall; You have two different calling conventions.  _*cdecl is all kernel stuff and all of the C++ methods are wrapped around in WINAPI (*_stdcall) passing conventions and __stdcall will clean do auto stack clean up and expect frame pointers inserted all over the place. And if you by accident use compiler options to trigger a __fastcall, it would be a pain to debug.

You can definitely hack something together, but do you really want to keep track of that in your user-space code and build environment? UGH I say.

Unless you have very specific engineering reasons to mix the two environments, (and no a unified build experience is not a valid reason, because you can get that from a batch file called buildall.bat) I say use the separate toolchains.

Comment: Sigh. Thanks(?) for confirming my fears...but if this is true, it is making me respect the NT DDK people less than already. e.g. Look at the scanner example w/a user mode component and a kernel mode component, it looks for the word "foul". But queries the sector size and splits across threads to check for it...so it can miss an "fo" split from a "ul" on the boundary. Not only are they prescribing building user mode (console) components under build, it *doesn't even work*! This is not relevant to my application (kernel mode piece just sends filenames in my case), just venting about their docs!

Comment: NTDDK is a b^#*& to work with ... I primarily do core kernel hacking on Linux, BSD, QNX etc. NT DDK has always given me pause.   Do you need to run a sophisticated scanner in the NT Kernel? I ported flex lexer skeleton and a bison skeleton to the linux kernel a while back because I needed serious parsing, and it could work in a single thread or across multiple threads for non-overlaping sentential evaluation paths. Can I help in some way?

Comment: Thank you for your help offer, I got up this morning and took my cobbled together catastrophe of a project and put it on GitHub... if you by chance are looking for work this is a very partial step toward ["CloneLocker"](https://github.com/hostilefork/CloneLocker) which is needed by a friend.  Contact me if you wish: `brian@hostilefork.com`!